# My code does not return the correct view in Django

Tags: django

View

```py
def compose(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.POST["confirmation"] is True:
            form = ComposeForm()
            return render(request,"practice/compose.html",{"form":form})
        else: 
            a = reverse("practice:index")
            return HttpResponseRedirect(a)

    else:
        a = reverse("practice:index")
        return HttpResponseRedirect(a)
```

Form

```html
    <form action= "{% url 'practice:Compose' %} " method=post>
        Do you want to send emails to the following list?<br>
        <br>
        <button name="confirmation" type="submit" value="True">Yes</button>
        <button name="confirmation" type="submit" value="False">No</button>
    </form>
```

When the Yes button was clicked, the index page was shown. However, it should have executed
`return render(request,"practice/compose.html",{"form":form})`

I suspect my if and else are wrong. Please help, thanks!

Comment: Did you debug this? When you print `request.POST["confirmation"]` it presumably prints `True` so you might think that the `is True` test would succeed. However, variables have a type and a value. The left-hand side of this test is different in both type and value to the right-hand side. If you print `type(request.POST["confirmation"])` for example you will see that it is a string (<class 'str'>) but `type(True)` is a boolean (<class 'bool'>). You can also see this in the Python REPL: `"True" is True` results in False. Additionally, the `is` test differs from the `==` test (as indicated below).

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504717/why-does-comparing-strings-using-either-or-is-sometimes-produce-a-differe

Comment: @jarmod, yes, now I realized the mistake that I made! Your explanation is very clear! I regret not learning the Python basics well enough! :(

Comment: It's never too late. Highly recommend: https://realpython.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the `is True` checks if `request.POST['confirmation']` refers to the *same* object, but such `QueryDict` maps strings to *strings*, hence it can never be `True`. You can match with the `'True'` string:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def compose(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.POST['confirmation'] == 'True':
        form = ComposeForm()
        return render(request,"practice/compose.html",{'form':form})
    return redirect('practice:index')
```

Comment: Thank you! I was asking python to check if  a string "True" is a boolean True so the answer will always be no. Thanks for your help!